# PWA multiple virtual paths with same backend code does not create separate installs

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have a generic common NodeJS app that multiple users access. The users are identified via the path. For example: `https://someapp.web.app/abc` can be one path while `https://someapp.web.app/def` can be another path.

On the NodeJS server path, I `send` the same server code by passing the path parameters to the program. The route appears something like this:

```
app.get('/*', async (req, res) => {
    ...
    locals.path = req.path;
    ...
    res.render('index', locals);
}
```

In the above `index` is a template that uses locals data for customisation

What I would like is that for each path there is a separate manifest and its associated icons and that on a single device (phone or desktop) multiple installations be possible. Thus, `https://someapp.web.app/abc` be one icon and `https://someapp.web.app/def` be another icon.

I am having difficulty in the placement and the scoping of the manifest and service worker. It always adds only one icon (the first path installed) to the home screen or desktop. My settings are:

In the public (root) folder I have each manifest viz. `abc-manifest.json` and `def-manifest.json` and a common `sw.js`.

The `abc-manifest.json` is:

```
  'scope': '/abc',
  'start_url': '/abc',
  ...
```

The access to the service-worker from the index.js is:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
      .then(function (registration) {
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration succeeded');
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed:', error);
      });
  }
```

I have tried changing the paths of scope and start_url to `/` but it did not work. Since all requests to the public path are common and not within the virtual `/abc` path, I am unable to figure out how to get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could that be an option to have a dedicated route that will redirect the user to `/abc` or `/def`?

In the manifest:

```
{
  "start_url": "https://example.com/login",
  "scope": "https://example.com/",
}
```

`/login` would make sure to redirect to `/abc` or `/def`.

This way you could keep one service worker, and one manifest.

And in the Service Worker, maybe try to return the specific icon based on file name.

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', e => {

  // Serve correct icon
  let url = new URL(e.request.url)
  if (url.pathname.contains('/android-icon-512.png')) {
    return respondWith(e, '/android-icon-512-abc.png')
  }
  // other ifs…

  // Return from cache or fallback to network.
  respondWith(e, e.request)
})

const respondWith = (e, url) =>
  e.respondWith(caches.match(url)
    .then(response => response || fetch(e.request).then(response => response))
  )
```

Maybe you’ll need a specific header to do this, or use a URL parameter (`icon.png?user=abc`) to help query the right icon. I’m throwing idea, because it probably depends a lot on your app back-end and/or front-end architecture.

I once did this: the back-end (PHP / Laravel) handled the correct returning of the icon and manifest (I had one for each use case) based on other stuff.